deleting disks also removed the instant snapshots in GCP
I deleted few disks but then their instant snapshots are also gone, there is not trace of the snapshots in GCP console.
the documentation clearly mentions that disk delete wont delete the snapshots. any way to recover from this.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/delete

I understand that you would like to know why your instant snapshots are not visible anymore after deleting some of the disks. Please correct me if I misunderstood.
I tried to replicate this in my test environment by categorizing this issue into two possible scenarios :

Creating a snapshot and instant snapshot by using a disk which is already in use by a VM :

In this scenario, I noticed that after deleting the VM associated with the disk used to create both the standard snapshot and instant snapshot, the disk got deleted but the standard snapshot and instant snapshot created by using that disk were still visible.


Creating a new disk thereby creating a snapshot and instant snapshot using that newly created disk :

In this scenario, I noticed that after deleting the newly created disk which is used to create both the standard snapshot and instant snapshots, resulted in deletion of the instant snapshot too.



I would like to clarify that instant snapshots are different from archive/standard snapshots. Please note that instant snapshots is a preview feature and the documentation you are mentioning is completely responsible for archive & standard disk snapshots.
To answer your first query, from the second bullet point in this document, it is mentioned that, “You can't delete a disk until you delete all the instant snapshots of the disk”, meaning, to delete a disk, all of the associated instant snapshots of that disk would be deleted. To Conclude, it is obvious that the delete operation would have deleted the instant snapshots internally to complete the deletion of that particular disk.
To answer your second query, from the last bullet point in this document, it is mentioned that, “You can't recover deleted instant snapshots.”
Having said that, I would like to confirm that this is completely expected behavior. For more information regarding this, please refer to :

Method: disks.delete
Archive and Standard Disk Snapshots
Instant Snapshots

I hope the above provided information is helpful.
Thanks & Regards,
Manish Bavireddy.

Hi Manish, please don't comment everywhere that this is working as expected, I have confirmation from the product team that this is a bug and that they are looking into it.

Hi StarLord, I have already mentioned that this is a preview feature, meaning that the feature may not be complete and is solely for testing purposes. The deletion process of a resource in Google Cloud Console works differently by automatically deleting the dependent resources when compared to Google Cloud CLI. This behavior could be seen in other cloud services as well, for example, deleting the cloud armor security policies from Cloud Console & Cloud CLI. That is the reason for mentioning it as an expected behavior.

Since you got the confirmation from the product team, could you please provide the link to the case, if it is an issue tracker which helps others with the same issue to track .
